# Google firebase background push notification to FCM token doesn't work

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to send a background push notification to my react native app using google firebase. When trying to send a notification to the FCM token using https://console.firebase.google.com/ I do not receive anything, no matter if the app is closed or opened.

Here is the whole code :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import CameraScreen from './CameraScreen';
import 'react-native-screens';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import SignInScreen from './SignInScreen';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import TestScreen from './TestScreen';
import Hub from './Hub';
import Creer from './Creer';
import Rejoindre from './Rejoindre';
import Album from './Album'; 
import Timeline from './Timeline';
import Profil from './Profil';
import SignUpScreen from './SignUpScreen';
import {AuthProvider} from './AuthContext';
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useAuth} from './AuthContext'; 
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (requestUserPermission) {

      messaging()
        .getToken()
        .then(token => {
          console.log("FCM token :",token);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('Failed Token Status', authStatus);
    }

    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
        }
      });

    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
    });

    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    });

    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeScreen"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{title: 'HomeScreen', headerShown: false}} 
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};


export default App;
```

My code does run and it does log the FCM token `LOG FCM token : cNhLSR_IS8S6LLpBVP[...]DaEZLpjnKI_Ug`so this part works.